# Erro no eclipse

Tags: java, path, build

Instalei e configurei o java jdk 9.0.1 e também o eclipse como java ide,no eclipse quando crio o projecto dá me logo erro[image: erro que da na consola]

e assim que começo a escrever "System.out.println" aoarece esta janela de erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso resolver isto?Obrigado

Comment: *Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'OlaEclipse'* - Sugere que você está usando o Java 9, mas ele procura o Java 8.

Comment: Qual sua versão do eclipse? Se for neon, atualize para oxygen, que já suporta o java9 completamente.

Comment: o erro deu no mars2

Comment: Olha essa tópico semelhante: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798326/1964435

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você sabe, o Java 9 ainda precisa de muitos ajustes, e os ambientes de desenvolvimento também precisam estar preparados para receber esses ajustes.

Quando eu instalei o Java 9 no meu Ubuntu também encontrei diversas dificuldades, então segui esse tutorial: [Configure Eclipse for Java 9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9).

Uma observação importante, é que você precisa configurar a sua variável de ambiente, tanto no Linux, quanto no Windows. No iOS eu não sei... não tenho suporte nesse SO.

O Eclipse que vai funcionar é somente a **versão Oxygen**. Somente essa versão tem suporte ao Java 9.

Agora vamos lá!

### Primeiro passo: Instale o Java 9 JDK

Para baixar o arquivo de instalação, [clique neste link!](http://jdk.java.net/9)
Como o foco não é instalação e sim configuração do JDK, vamos ao próximo ponto...

### Segundo Passo: Configurando a variável de ambiente no Windows 10

Há casos em que o sistema operacional Windows já reconhece de forma automática. Mas no meu caso, ao contrário disso, preciso resolver de forma manual acessando as configurações avançadas do Sistema Operacional e apontar o caminho de instalação do Java 9 na variável PATH.

1. Na janela do windows, clique com o seu botão direito do mouse em cima do botão de menu iniciar, e vá até a opção **Sistema**
2. Agora, vá em **Informações do Sistema**
3. Clique agora em alterar configurações
4. Clique na aba avançado
5. Clique em Variáveis de ambiente
6. Em variáveis do sistema, busque pela variável **Path**
7. Clique em editar
8. Encontre o caminho de instalação do Java 9. Geralmente, no Windows está assim: c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
9. Este caminho - Que pode ser outro como eu disse, mas na maioria dos casos é este - precisa ser apontado na sua variável de ambiente.

Confirme tudo!

Agora, para ver se está funcionando, você pode criar uma classe no Java com uma main e fazer um "Hello World" clássico!

Espero ter contribuído!

Comment: Mudei para a versão oxygen e já está a funcionar.Obrigado

Comment: o meu problema é que estava a usar uma versão errada do eclipse que era a mars2 agora estou a usar o oxygen e está tudo bem...obrigado

Comment: Que ótimo que conseguiu resolver o problema... é importante que marque como resolvido esse problema. O link que enviei para você nesta resposta relata isso.

Comment: @CarlosHelberger para configurar você pode conferir neste link: https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Olá @CarlosHeuberger. Muito bom seu ponto de vista. Vou melhorar meu posicionamento em relação a isso. sobre a variável PATH no Windows 7, eu já tive problemas de ter que apontar. Não sei o por quê disso, mas em qualquer sistema operacional, é possível se esperar qualquer coisa.